# How to redirect urls after rewriting in .htaccess without getting redirect loop?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

for example

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#FOR STATIC URLS
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [NC,L]
```

now tell how to redirect above without redirect loop error or any other method for successful redirect...

Comment: What URL causes redirect loop?

Comment: suppose if i do
`Redirect 301 folder1.php http://example.com/folder2/`
It says **This webpage has a redirect loop error** in Chrome and **The page isn't redirecting properly** error in Firefox, tell me how to redirect after rewriting.

Comment: Why are you doing `Redirect 301 folder1.php` when you already have `RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [NC,L]` ?

Comment: Because its just for rewrite, after doing both old and new urls are working but i want old urls to redirect at new.